# Trouble cellForRowAtIndexPath in multi section tableView in parse.com

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am having trouble using cellForRowAtIndexPath in a tableView from Parse.com The code I am running is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListadoInventarioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var sectionTitle:String = timelineData1.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as String
        var sectionAnimals:Array = porBodega[sectionTitle]!

        // This is the line with problems
        var animal:String = sectionAnimals.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
        cell.textLabel?.text = animal
}
```

Problem is variable porBodega is a Dictionary of type String: ArrayOfPFObject , so sectionAnimals is an array of PFObjects. If I do a println(porBodega), I get this:

```
[Oficina: [
<InventarioObjetos:wObhxQ98oz:(null)> {
    Bodega = Oficina;
    Categoria = "Equipo de monta\U00f1a";
    Descripcion = Chalecos;
    FechaDeEntrada = "2012-04-01 19:44:00 +0000";
    Marca = "O'rageous";
    Modelo = "VM-001";
    NumeroDeInventario = CSOV002;
    NumeroDeSerie = NA;
    Status = Usado;
    Tamano = M;
}, 
<InventarioObjetos:u3Yn80lXU8:(null)> {
    Bodega = Oficina;
    Categoria = "Equipo de monta\U00f1a";
    Descripcion = Chalecos;
    FechaDeEntrada = "2012-04-01 19:44:00 +0000";
    Marca = "O'rageous";
    Modelo = "VM-001";
    NumeroDeInventario = CSOV003;
    NumeroDeSerie = NA;
    Status = Usado;
    Tamano = M;
}
]]
```

So I do not know how to get a specific data form one of my objects, like the variable Modelo and then set it up in the cell text label. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListadoInventarioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var sectionTitle:String = timelineData1.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as String
        var sectionAnimals:Array = porBodega[sectionTitle]!

        let animal:PFObject = sectionAnimals[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = animal.objectForKey("modelo") as String
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: /Users/jesusguerrero/Downloads/Apps/inventario/inventario/ListadoInventarioTableViewController.swift:241:39: 'Dictionary<String, Array<PFObject>>' does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'

Comment: Changed to let animal:PFObject = sectionAnimals.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
The error I get is: /Users/jesusguerrero/Downloads/Apps/inventario/inventario/ListadoInventarioTableViewController.swift:241:39: 'Array<PFObject>' does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'

Comment: @JesúsGuerreroAlmaraz see my edit, and dont forget to return the cell